# Gnome Shell Viber icon doesn't show up but it's "there" without an icon

Tags: command-line, gnome, icons, viber

In Ubuntu 15.04 using Gnome Shell, the Viber 4.2.2 icon disappears both using native indicator bar and the topicon extension.